# How to embed flash video in a web app for mobile devices?

Tags: video, mobile

I have a web app with flash video on it (using FlowPlayer) and it doesn't work on mobile phones. What do I need to do to play video on mobile phones? What player can do that? Or what video format?

The phone I tried it on is my fiance's Moto Q. I'm guessing some phones can play Flash, but what will work for most phones?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [h264](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/technologies/h264/) or/and [Ogg Vorbis](http://www.vorbis.com/). [Video for everyone](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) will most definetly help you.